# JSON with Unicode attributes

Tags: javascript, json, web, unicode, attributes

I am developing a web app and I want to use JSON objects with Unicode attributes such as the following:

```
a = {
ονομα:"hello"
}
```

And then use it like that

```
a.ονομα
```

Or maybe iterate over the object

I have tried it in the chrome console and it works fine but I would like to know if it is supported in other browsers and if it's a good practice.

Comment: Yes, you *can* do it. But *should* you? No.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is it a bad practise? The app will be only for Greeks and supported by Greeks

Comment: That may be, but until you can write "if( ... ) { ... } else { ... }` in Greek, you should keep your code in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with JavaScript 1.5 a JavaScript identifier, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

Looking at the browser compatibility for JS 1.5, you should be safe as even IE6-7 run that version.

For more detailed info check: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/96656).

Comment: You can also use correctly spelled Greek words such as όνομα (with the tonos accent) as identifiers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names